# Меня терроризирует учитель!

Tags: стилистика

Наш новый учитель по русскому (с 9 класса по 11) ставит мне заниженные оценки (по моему мнению). В частности: ни за одно сочинение мне не была поставлена нормальная оценка, только кол. Причина всегда одна и та же: "Это эссе по обществознанию, а не сочинение по литературе", "Ты не читал произведения", "Бессмысленный набор слов". Приведу два примера: одно сочинение из 10 класса, одно недавнее. Раньше меня не волновало, но сейчас это портит мне аттестат.

1. Тема: Ваш ответ на вопрос героя Ф.М.Достоевского: "Не загладится ли одно крошечное преступление тысячами добрых дел?"

Далее моё сочинение:
Не загладится ли одно крошечное преступление тысячами добрых дел? На самом деле это не такой уж сложный вопрос. Если внимательно рассмотреть примеры из реальной жизни, то мнения по этому поводу могут разделиться. Кто-то считает, что переступление закона не допустимо ни в коем случае, даже если это разумно или жизненно необходимо. Такие люди ставят закон превыше всего, считают его величайшим достижением цивилизации, основой мирного существования. Но есть люди, разделяющие другую позицию: они считают, что преступление может загладится добрыми делами. Такие люди думают, что конечная цель оправдывает средства. Они способны на жестокость, часто не способны испытывать жалость. Я могу понять и тех, и других, но мне близка позиция, что закон - превыше всего.
(Z) В правильности такой точки зрения меня убеждает художественная литература, история, личный опыт. Но мне хотелось бы вспомнить произведения художественной литературы, где раскрывается тема мотива при совершении преступления: Родион Романович Раскольников, бедный студент - оправдывает жестокое преступление великой целью. Гнусное убийство, ложь, воровство он оправдывает тем, что убийство никчёмной старушки - дело плёвое и даже полезное, а её богатства пойдут на великие дела. Тем не менее никаких великих дел он не осуществил, добрых дел не сделал. Я думаю, что для этого существуют разные причины: либо теория не верна, и преступление не может быть оправдано даже в глазах преступника, если он достаточно человечен, либо теория верна, и Раскольников не является сверхчеловеком. Я думаю, писатель хочет донести мысль о том, что закон - не пустое место, он не возник из-за прихоти родителей, он - предмет достижения счастья, искупления грехов, очищения. То есть автор считает, что теория не верна, и я с ним согласен.
(Z) Другой, совершенно противоположный пример я нашёл в рассказе Гоголя "Мёртвые души". В рассказе "Мёртвые души" есть легенда о гордом и красивом человеке. Главный герой, после совершения гнусных дел, ради своего собственного блага, уезжает как ни в чём не бывало. Ему допустили совершить корыстные дела и отпустили безнаказанным. Главный герой является примером "успешного" преступника, и я думаю, что автор хочет донести мысль о том, что преступление остаётся безнаказанным, если закон не работает.
(Z) Таким образом мы убедились в том, что никакое преступление не возможно загладить. Преступление - это средство для достижения исключительно своей собственной выгоды. Не зря история рассказывает, что даже великий мудрец древности, Сократ, перед своей казнью сказал: Не в зависимости от того, нравится вам закон или нет, он действителен до тех пор, пока не упразднён. Закон - священнейший долг цивилизованого человека.

2. Тема: Человек в обществе. "В чём смысл жизни?" (Господин из Сан-Франциско).

Далее моё сочинение: В чём же смысл жизни? На самом деле вопрос требует переформулировки для дальнейшей работы с ним, для ответа на него. Человек в мире должен не просто существовать, в таком случае вопрос будет звучать: "в чём смысл существования, зачем мне каждое утро вставать и для чего?". Смысл существования - в жизни, самом процессе наслаждения существованием в мире. Но обычно под словом "жизнь" и подразумевают "существование в мире, сосуществование в обществе". Так странно получается, что смысл жизни в том, чтобы жить. И я это докажу!
(Z) Доказывать будем на примере произведения Ивана Алексеевича Бунина "Господин из Сан-Франциско". В начале рассказа Господин садится на параход "Атлантида", его название как бы намекает, что он везёт людей забывшихся, как и сама Атлантида - город затопленный, всеми забытый и никому не нужный. Параход является метафорой жизни Господина. Как думал сам Господин - он только начинал жить, а до этого только работал, копил, ради того, чтобы именно сегодня начать жить. Но спустя крайне непродолжительное время он, как ни странно, умирает, так и не повидав жизни. Гроб, в котором его похоронили, - даже не является гробом -, есть аллегория на жизнь Господина, а точнее -  не жизнь, а простое копчение неба, безвольное, безынициативное существование. Именно этим существованием он "заменил" жизнь, поэтому и гроб - коробка для соды, неодушевлённой вещи. Как и сам Господин. (Z) Я считаю, что это прямое доказательство того, что жизнь неотдельна от существования, в любой момент времени надо наслаждаться жизнью. Смысл человеческой жизни в том, чтобы наслаждаться ею ли просто жить.

3. Правда ли это бессмысленный набор слов, который не примут в качестве итогового сочинения. Допустят ли меня к ЕГЭ, объективны ли колы, которые мне ставят?

Comment: 1) Мне понравилось, но я не специалист! 2) Закон превыше всего? Комментируя первое предложение Торы: «В начале сотворил Б-г небо и землю», Раши говорит: «Сказано: сотворил Б-г (Судья), и не сказано: сотворил Г-сподь (Милосердный). Ибо вначале вознамерился сотворить (мир) на основе (строгого) правосудия, но, увидев, что мир не может так существовать, выслал вперед милосердие и соединил его с правосудием.

Comment: Прочитал первое ваше сочинение. Что сказать? Если объективно - это не кол, однако такое сочинение максимум тянет на оценку "удовлетворительно". Вас еще с 5-го класса должны были учить тому, что любая мысль должна быть доказана. Для этого в тексте должны использоваться цитаты из художественного произведения, которые подтверждают ваши мысли. Вы же дальше пересказа основных событий произведения не двигаетесь, а только поверхностно о них рассуждаете. Что касается грамотности: здесь тоже не все так хорошо, много ошибок: орфографических, пунктуационных и т.д.

Comment: Вторая причина, как мне кажется, в следующем: учитель убедился в том, что вы попросту не читаете текст. Да-да, учителя прекрасно знают о наличии в сети интернет кратких пересказов. Читая их, вы обманываете прежде всего себя, поскольку никакой пользы для вас это занятие не несет. Знание краткого содержания помогает создать "видимость прочтения", однако любой подкованный учитель сразу поймет, читал ли ученик текст полностью или нет, задав вам несколько уточняющих вопросов по тексту. И теперь я спрошу: зачем пытаться хитрить, если вы видите, что это не работает. Просто начните читать...

Comment: Смысл человеческого существования состоит в том, тобы в течение подаренной жизни построить собственное «я», способное удостоиться вечного наслаждения близости к Творцу. Близость в Духовном мире измеряется не метрами, а подобием качеств. Т.е. за жизнь человек так должен исправить свои качества (а приобретения некоторых - удостоиться), чтобы они стали МАКСИМАЛЬНО подобными качествам Создателя!

Comment: @Алёнушка, а вы прям чувствуете близость создателя сами, или просто сверяетесь по совпадению качеств, что на правильном пути?

Comment: @user190920, 1) 100 видеоуроков рава Ашера Кушнира по книге «Месилат йешарим — Путь праведных»: https://toldot.com/tv/video/?theme=860 2) Про смысл жизни: https://toldot.com/life.html 3) мне до праведности далеко, но сверяться нужно.

Comment: Нормальные сочинения. Видно, что писавший сам размышлял, а не сдирал из учебника и разных добролюбовых. А бессмысленный набор слов здесь тоже есть, но не в сочинениях)))